# Can't change IP to static on debian beaglebone

Tags: linux, ip, debian, beagleboneblack, static-ip-address

I'm currently working with a beaglebone black and want to evade the whole dhcp issue. I'm trying to change my IP to remain static; however, after I've done all of that and inputted my dns (since resolvconf is installed), it still won't change the IP even though i've restarted the networks and the entire beaglebone. It also seems like even when I mess with the code in /etc/network/interfaces by changing the usb's IP, placing fubar etc -- that updating the network doesn't affect the ifconfig. I'm thinking that the network is grabbing these address from somewhere else and I'm not sure how to find that. Below is my code in /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
# Example to keep MAC address between reboots
#hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE

# The secondary network interface
#allow-hotplug eth1
#iface eth1 inet dhcp

# WiFi Example
#auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet static
#    wpa-ssid "essid"
#    wpa-psk  "TMS"

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# ... or on host side, usbnet and random hwaddr
# Note on some boards, usb0 is automaticly setup with an init script
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.31.49.168
        netmask 255.255.252.0
        gateway 10.31.49.253
        dns-domain tms.local
        dns-nameserver 10.31.49.6
iface usb0 inet static
        address 192.168.7.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.7.0
        gateway 192.168.7.1
        dns-nameservers 10.31.49.6
        dns-search lan
```

Please let me know what I can do. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will answer your question, but, the BBB debian distribution uses connman to manage the network. 
I've also not been able to get a static IP address to work, but maybe this will help in your research.